# Ubuntu-Mate doesn't show YouTube comments

Tags: 18.04, firefox, google-chrome, youtube, ubuntu-mate

Can't see comments neither with Chrome nor with Firefox.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  You should provide more details, such as version of Ubuntu-Mate, plus ideally an example of a video that you can't see youtube comments on.  A huge percentage of videos on youtube don't have comments (denied by owners/creators), probably 60% of the ones I look at are this way (*being set by youtube, and the browser used is not part of the issue*)

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu-Mate 18.04.

Comment: Do you see comments on [this official Ubuntu 18.04 LTS MATE video](https://youtu.be/V6kth-4M62o)? I see them in place.

Comment: No, I don't. Here is the screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/iWtgIDV

Comment: You should be able to see comments in browsers without the need of adding any extension. From the image you posted, you have quite a few extensions already that maybe responsible for **preventing** the display of comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't an OS-based issue, though, you should look for help with your browsers. Particularly, try to launch each without extensions, tracking protection and other stuff. Clearing browser data is also desirable.

Comment: After trying, to no avail, with Firefox extensions disabled I added Zoom Page WE and using it could see comments. Thanks!